# SIGABRT when accessing UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I'm used to loading ViewControllers from storyboard files or xib files, so when I first tried to load one in code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;

ProfileViewController *profViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfileView"];

NSLog(@"Self View Frame: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(self.view.frame.size));
NSLog(@"ProfViewCont Frame: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(profViewController.view.frame.size));
```

I got the following error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderMutableString initWithString:]: nil argument'

What do I need to do differently assuming that my storyboard xib is loaded properly?  Here is the viewDidLoad:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // add subviews

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.view.opaque = YES;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 480)];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75f];
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    // Sort stat bars top to bottom (HP == 0):
    statBars = [statBars
                sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id label1, id label2)
                {
                    if ([label1 frame].origin.y < [label2 frame].origin.y)
                        return NSOrderedAscending;
                    else
                        return NSOrderedDescending;
                }];

    // Sort types left to right:
    types = [types
             sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id label1, id label2)
             {
                 if ([label1 frame].origin.x < [label2 frame].origin.x)
                     return NSOrderedAscending;
                 else
                     return NSOrderedDescending;
             }];

    [self displayInfo:currentIndex];
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, it turns out the error was in [self displayInfo:currentIndex] the last line in ViewDidLoad.  I mistakenly thought that viewDidLoad was safely called when the ViewController was instantiated.  It turns it is called much later, when I called self.view.

<_<  lazy initialization, huh?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `ProfileViewController` xib , you must have connected some wrong outlet to the file owner